# Can you get electricity from your mobile phone

Tags: charging, energy, discharge, mobile, electricity

Does someone know if its possible to get energy from your phone (android/ios)? I want to charge a capacitor or a very little Battery and thought about the idea to get this energy from your mobile phone (with a cable which you plug in like the normal charging cable).

Possible or not (please explain)?

Comment: Take the battery out and put the capacitor on the battery +/- terminals. And void your warranty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Android it is possible in [OTG mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go).

Your phone becomes Master/Host and supplies energy to a Slave device (a mouse, a storage device, etc..):

> USB OTG defines two roles for devices: OTG A-device and OTG B-device, specifying which side supplies power to the link, and which initially is the host. **The OTG A-device is a power supplier, and an OTG B-device is a power consumer**. In the default link configuration, the A-device acts as a USB host with the B-device acting as a USB peripheral.

You have to connect the ID pin of the connector to Ground:

> The device with a mini-A plug inserted became an OTG A-device, and the device with a mini-B plug inserted became a B-device (see above). The type of plug inserted was detected by the state of the ID pin (the mini-A plug's ID pin was grounded, while the mini-B plug's was floating).

[image]

In case of iOS it is technically possible because there are accessories that use power from the plug, but the process of fabricating a compatible device has many more hassles, such as applying to be a [developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/), etc..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much "very little" is the audio jack might be an alternative - for those phones that still have it.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395818/3984613) suggests that the four-ring TRRS connector for headphone/mic combinations provides a way to draw a little power of about 2.5 mW at a voltage of about 2 V. Other sources however state different voltage levels.

> Most use a 4-conductor TRRS connection with the following pin-out:
>
> TIP = left headphone out
>
> RING = right headphone out
>
> RING = ground
>
> SLEEVE = mic in + plug-in power

It would be necessary to adapt the impedance of your circuit to that of the phone's audio jack. Impedance matching (internal impedance of phone equals impedance of external circuit) results in maximized harvested power. Above mentioned answer indicates that the phone checks for the microphone's impedance (in the range of 200 .. 500 ohms). Find a little more insight [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Harvest-Power-from-an-Audio-Jack/).